# How to create a search button and find elements in specific path ?

Tags: css, html

i am new in html and css so i would like to create a search button in my webpage and it find the typed  word in a specific path in linux for example :

word i am looking for : 123456
main path to find : /home/packages/

inside of the above path it contains several folders for example :

/home/packages/WW1/hour/

and inside of the above path it contains several files, but the file that i am looking for has a code like this : 123456.deb

for basically that i am try to do is if i put some code in the search button it must return the path where the 123456.deb is

the code that i have is the following

in the css

```
input[type=text] {
width: 150px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 3px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: white;
background-image: url('searchicon.png');
background-position: 10px 10px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 10px 20px 12px 40px;
-webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
float:right;
padding-top: 1px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
padding-left: 1px;
padding-right: 1px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
width: 50%;
}
```

in html doc

any help wil be appreciated

Comment: You've forgot to include html.

Comment: Sorry, this is the html : https://github.com/IntelGraphics/webpages/blob/master/HTML/index.html

Comment: The code regarding the search bar is below the comment (search bar) ;)